# Test de servicio REST con Arquillian. Valor de entity de response es nulo

Tags: rest, java-8, test

Tengo un problema con un test case de Arquillian.

Codigo:

```
@Stateless
public class CustomerResourceImpl implements CustomerResource{
    @Override
    public Response findOne(String id) {
        String res = "Un cliente";
        return Response.ok(res).build();
    }
}

@Path("customer")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface CustomerResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/findOne")
    public javax.ws.rs.core.Response findOne(@QueryParam("id") String id);
}
```

Test case:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class CustomerResourceTest {

    @Deployment (testable = false)
    public static Archive createTestArchive() {
        return ShrinkWrap
                ..... (mas)
                .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    }
    
    @ArquillianResource
    private URL deploymentURL;

    @Test
    @RunAsClient
    public void findOne(@ArquillianResteasyResource CustomerResource resource) throws Exception {
        final Response response = resource.findOne("1");
        System.out.println(response.getEntity()); // IS NULL ??
        System.out.println(response.getStatus()); // 200 OK
        assertNotNull(response);
    }       
}
```

El problema es que el metodo response.getEntity() siempre devuelve nulo.
El status es 200 y el servicio funciona bien en el servidor real.
El servicio esta deployado en servidor jboss 7 con Java 8

Gracias!

Comment: Hola Carlos, esta es una comunidad en español. Podrías editar tu pregunta para que sea comprendida por la comunidad. En todo caso, si quieres mantener tu idioma te recomiendo publiques esto en [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la solucion en este link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48781860/getentity-vs-readentity-in-response-javax-ws-rs

Debe usarse el metodo "readEntity"